# How to press editor action on Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

How do you press the Editor Action key on Android softkey using Espresso?
I tried:

`onView(withId(R.id.test_title)).perform(typeText("Sample Title"), pressKey(KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION));`

But it's not working.. Any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"pressKey" expects a KEYCODE, not a FLAG. So pressKey(KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION) doesn't really make sense and will definitely not work.

But there is a ViewAction for pressing the editor (IME) action, see the static method:  ViewActions#pressImeActionButton()

You can view the Espresso 1.x implementation details here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#pressImeActionButton()

Comment: @yogutearl: Link is giving 404. If possible please update it

Answer (score 6):

Since this is a the top google result for someone searching how to send keys using Espresso, I'd like to provide an example: `onView(withId(R.id.your_id)).perform(ViewActions.pressKey(KeyEvent.YOUR_KEY));`

Answer (score 4):

To send a general key press in Espresso, use something like this:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU));
```

This, for example, will send the hardware Menu button event to any View, to open the Overflow Menu in the ActionBar/ToolBar.

---

<sup>Note: To quickly add the imports for these methods, put the blinking cursor on the unresolved method, then do Android Studio ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for `"show context action"` or `"show intention action"` ➔ click on the result option ➔ A popup window will appear ➔ click on `"Import static method ..."`. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Context Actions". [More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). Another way is to enable `"Add unambiguous imports on the fly"` in the Settings.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was not clear for me and others don't work.
The actual solution working is as below

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.search_box))
        .perform(ViewActions.pressImeActionButton())
```

where search_box is the id of my edittext.